# Can a heavy flash animation /interactive infographic be adapted or made into an app?

Tags: flash, animation, interactive

Hello Stackoverflow Communtiy,

My question is can this site's (http://www.mckinstry.com/) flash animation architecture/ interactive infographic be made or adapted into something more accessible like an app?

What would it take do to something like this. I need help wrapping my head around a project like this.

Thank you for any clarity.
-Ann K

Comment: Are you talking about a mobile app?

Comment: a web app first, then made available as a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

Accessible as in, "doesn't require the Flash Player to run?"

There are a few emerging frameworks that will render animation and interactivity using HTML5 Canvas. The one that aims to be the most familiar to Flash developers is [**EaselJS**](http://easeljs.com/). It's got some companion tools that let you export your existing .SWF files into it.

I've not used it, so I can't vouch. But it looks promising, as do the [examples](http://pirateslovedaisies.com/).

It's not the GUI/IDE system your Flash developers are used to working in, but it seems to offer something that's not too huge a leap.

Comment: Yes, Accessible as in "doesnt require Flash Player to run"  This looks looks to be something that is similar enough for them to work in, or at least I hope so. Thanks for the links @parisminton

Answer (score 0):

If you by "app" mean an app for iOS or Android, AIR can compile Flash content into an installable app:

http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

Comment: web app then down the road a mobile app